# How do I get my misdemeanor conviction removed from public records websites?

Tags: united-states, criminal-record, expungement, court-records

Awhile ago I was charged with a misdemeanor that ended up with me paying a fine and doing community service. I searched my name on Google the other day and so far only saw my charge on one public records website. I'm currently working on getting my record expunged. After I get it expunged will it be removed from public records websites or do I have to show them proof of the expungement so it won't affect me in the future?

Comment: Can you clarify the jurisdiction where the conviction was occurred? Also, can you clarify what you mean by "public records website"? Is it a website that posts booking photos? One where you pay to get a background check? 

I understand that you don't want to list the website, but the more details the better because those distinctions can change how you proceed.

Comment: The charge occurred earlier this year. The other day I was curious to see if my charge was public or not so I type my full name in the Google search engine and so far I saw on a website where they post your criminal record for everyone to see. Also, this website gives you the option to remove it by showing proof that you got it expunged or paying a small fee, but people keep saying that its a scam and its gonna be on the internet forever whether its expunged or not. I want to be a software engineer someday and don't want to ruin my chances years down the line.

Comment: I am still a little confused. Can you provide the website? Is it one that does criminal history searches?

Comment: its called atlaspublicrecords.com

Comment: all I want to know is will it still affect me years down the line regardless of whether I get it expunged.

Comment: What state did this occur? It could be helpful to know their expungement statute. Some states specifically say that you may lawfully deny the arrest and conviction. See Fla. Stat. § 943.0585. http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=&URL=0900-0999/0943/Sections/0943.0585.html

Comment: @KingAlexander Even if this website removes it, tools like the way back machine can maintain archived content of internet content that has been deleted by the original person posting it. Obliterating history is never completely possible. In the same way, if your court proceedings were reported in a local newspaper (the local paper in the small town where I grew up did that), an expungement doesn't give you the right to alter the newspaper's archives. Expungement allows you to avoid the collateral consequences of a conviction but not the right to 100% hide the historical fact in all situations.

Answer (score 6):

Your question (when read with your follow-up comments) is somewhat complex, so I am going to make a few assumptions and break it down into several sub parts.

### Assumptions

- The conviction occurred in a state where the expungement statute allows you to tell employers that you were never arrested and convicted.
- When you say “public records websites” you’re asking about sites like atlaspublicrecords.com.
- That atlaspublicrecords.com is a US based company. They don’t list an address and the website used a private registration services, so can’t easily determine that they are US-based.

### Your questions and follow-up Considerations

> After I get it expunged, will it be removed from public records
>   websites . . . .

No. Websites like atlaspublicrecords.com do not link to actual public records. I searched a couple of common names and feel safe in assuming that it only collects and publishes the information—it does not actually link to court records.
Nevertheless, it would not be available from the actual government agencies that keep those records. By getting your records expunged the convictions and arrest would no longer be available as public records that someone could request from the courthouse, police department, or whatever state agency does criminal history in your jurisdiction.

> do I have to show them proof of the expungement . . . .

Yes, if you believe what the website claims. I can’t find a physical address for the website and don’t know if they are real or a scam, so understand that when you give them information about your expungement—or pay their silly fee, they might collect the money and do nothing. My opinion is that the company is shady and seems to operate in a gray area of the law that I will explain below.

**Options if they don’t remove the post:**

You could try to sue them for some type of [secondary dignitary       tort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dignitary_torts) like [defamation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defamation) or [false light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_light). But these would       have some significant legal hurdles. See [G.D. v. Kenny, 15 A.3d 300     (N.J. 2011)](http://www.leagle.com/decision/In%20NJCO%2020110131200.xml/G.D.%20v.%20KENNY), where the New Jersey Supreme Court held that       commenting on an expunged criminal records was not defamation or       invasion of privacy because it was the truth.

You could try to argue that they are a **consumer reporting agency**     under the Fair Credit Reporting Act (“FCRA”). If they're governed by     the FCRA, you have some additional legal remedies (like civil       penalties/fines) if they don't remove/clarify an expunged record. The    Fair Credit Reporting Act applies to credit reporting agencies, like     Experian & Equifax but also covers companies that compile and sell       information for background checks. This includes criminal records. See the [Federal Trade Commission’s Advisory Opinion to LeBlanc (06-09-98)](https://www.ftc.gov/policy/advisory-opinions/advisory-opinion-leblanc-06-09-98).

But . . . this website is operating in a gray area that appears to comply with the law. The FCRA only  applies to consumer reporting agencies, which are defined as:

> Any person which, for **monetary fees, dues, or on a cooperative nonprofit basis**, regularly engages in whole or in part in the practice of assembling or evaluating consumer credit information or other information on consumers for the purpose of furnishing consumer reports to third parties, and which uses any means or facility of interstate commerce for the purpose of preparing or furnishing consumer reports. 
>
> 15 U.S.C. § 1681a(f)

Because they’re not charging money or a fee to access the reports and they’re not a nonprofit cooperative, they probably do not meet the definition of a CRA.

Bottom-line is that you're best option is to give them the expungement documents once you obtain them.

Answer (score 4):

No, expungement does not give you rights to have the internet purged of your conviction.  Public records sites *might* be interested in updating their records to reflect the expungement, but any media that reported on the incident will probably decline to remove or modify their records.  Internet caches will continue to show whatever was available online in the past.

And if you think that's not fair (which is a reasonable complaint) consider that at least you got a hearing: [People defamed by law enforcement officials](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/10887/10) who never even end up charged with a crime can have their lives ruined, generally with *no* recourse.

Comment: Don't know what media has to do with this because it was nothing like that. If you don't know what you're talking about then don't comment on my question.

Comment: Lucky for you I *do* know what I am talking about.  Hence, this comment is on my *answer* to your question.  To clarify my use of the term "media:" For purposes of your question, you can consider any website not operated by the government entities subject to the expungement order to be "online media."

Comment: So even though I get this expunged companies can see this on the internet and I'll never get a job?

Comment: @KingAlexander as far as i'm aware you have no right to have it removed. If you lived in the EU you could ask google to delist it, but that can take a while. In a constantly online you have to be more careful how you behave as evidence can be permanent.

Comment: "companies can see this on the Internet" yes, "I'll never get a job" no.  I mean, it does depend on what and when, but you are not _doomed._  You can find work.  It might not be very good work but there will hopefully be some.